# Надо ли обособлять "в моменты глубокой задумчивости"?

Tags: пунктуация

Он был мечтателем - настолько, что порой(,) в моменты глубокой задумчивости(,) переставал замечать окружающий мир.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Он был мечтателем — настолько, что порой, **в моменты глубокой задумчивости,** переставал замечать окружающий мир.*

Обстоятельственный временной оборот обособляется, так как **уточняет** предыдущее обстоятельство "порой", раскрывает его содержание (когда именно).

Другие отношения между обстоятельствами (неоднородные или однородные) здесь подходят в меньшей степени.